# Clearing a hung SSAS refresh process

Tags: ssas, ssas-tabular

On SSAS 2017 Tabular, I have SQL Agent jobs that run some t-sql steps and ssis packages and finish with an SSAS refresh. I have hundreds of these across three servers. (This is a system I have inherited so it was not my design to have two SQL Server instances and two SSAS instances on each of the three Windows VMs!)

Roughly once a week or so I get a "long running job" alert and it is always the final SSAS step on which it is stuck. It is a different job each time. The problem has been happening for a month or so and started around the time we implemented CU22.

Looking in $SYSTEM.DISCOVER_CONNECTIONS etc I see the Session spid and Connection Id, so can cancel using this type of thing:

```
<Cancel xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
    <ConnectionID>192507</ConnectionID>
    <SessionID>40C4F30C-CD9C-4F61-A664-5F97B1AE1E7C</SessionID>
    <SPID>983599</SPID>
    <CancelAssociated>1</CancelAssociated>
</Cancel>
```

This clears the connection and sets the Session Status from 1 to 3, which I believe means closed. If I try to execute a refresh, either manually through SSMS or by re-running the final job step, it just sits there doing nothing. I presume it is still being blocked by the original hung process.

$SYSTEM.DISCOVER_SESSIONS shows 0 Session_Idle_Time, 93 millisecs of Session_CPU_Time and 92807506 Session_Elapsed_Time. So, if it wasn't idle and isn't using a lot of cpu, what is it waiting for?

The only resolution at the moment is restarting SSAS, which is far from ideal.

Obviously I can run Profiler but I'd have to leave it running continually for a week or more to catch it.

I'm a DBA of many years but have never worked with SSAS before. What can I look at to find out what is causing the problem in SSAS?

Comment: Our experience so far has been: It is almost impossible for "us" (i.e., the application teams) to find the root cause. Contacting Microsoft support has helped us in the past.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found a solution. So simple I'm kicking myself.

All I had to do was replace this:
CancelAssociated>1</CancelAssociated
with this:
CancelAssociated>true</CancelAssociated